# Creating callable wrappers for data members with std::mem_fn

Tags: c++, c++11

It is possible to store and wrap member functions with `std::mem_fn`?

In C you can use `offsetof(...)` on a data member to crudely wrap it (but only for some types). Is it possible to wrap a data member in C++?  What's the cleanest way?

For example:

```
class X
{
    ...
    M m;
    ...
};

mem_var<M> xm = &X::m;

int main()
{
    X x = ...;
    M i = ...;
    xm(x) = i; // same as x.m = i
    cout << xm(x); // same as cout << x.m
}
```

Comment: If only we had polymorphic lambdas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with... `std::mem_fn`.

```
struct B
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    auto m = std::mem_fn(&B::y);

    B b {0, 0};
    m(b) = 4;

    printf("%d %d\n", b.x, b.y);    // prints 0 4
    printf("%d\n", m(b));           // prints 4

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/40nI2

Comment: Thanks, but what type do I use to store it? (you are using auto, I need to store it as a member variable)  Can I use function<...> to do so, and if so what are the correct type parameters for it?

Comment: Figured it out: Replace "auto" in your example with "std::function<int&(B&)>"

Comment: @user1131467: You could also use `decltype(std::mem_fn(&B::y))`.